# how to carry out few different set of instruction for string datatype in a template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template member function in a class that is called for all `bool`, `double`, `int` and `string`. I want to carry out few instructions that are common to all the above mentioned data types. But for `String` last few lines of code is different. So can any one suggest me a better way to carry out this in a same template function.

```
template< class T>

xyz (t* a)

{
       //few lines are common for all types for data

       //last 3 lines of code is different for Strings
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, as often, is to factorize the common behavior and provide a mean to specialize some parts of the algorithm (see the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern).

Here, you can do this quite easily by moving the last lines of your function in a function of its own, which can be specialized for certain data types. Remember that when it comes to functions, [overloading should be preferred to template specialization](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

```
template <class T>
void xyz(T * a)
{
    //few lines are common for all types for data

    xyz_finish(a);
}

template <class T>
void xyz_finish(T * a)
{
    // default case (can be empty)
}

void xyz_finish(std::string * s)
{
    // string case
}
```

Of course, your function should have a more descriptive name than the one I used...

You can also do the symmetrical operation: move the common behavior in a function, and overloads the "top-level" function:

```
template <class T>
void xyz(T * a)
{
    common_behavior(a);
}

void xyz(std::string * s)
{
    common_behavior(s);

    // code specific to strings
}

template <class T>
void common_behavior(T * a)
{
    //few lines that are common for all types for data
}
```

If you do not want or cannot create other functions, you can test the type of the parameter:

```
template <class T>
void xyz(T * a)
{
    // common code

    if (is_same<T, std::string>::value)
    {
        //code for strings
    }
}
```

`is_same` is a class template containing a value which is true if its two parameters are the same type, available in TR1, Boost and C++0x. This solution will work only if the code in the `if` clause is valid for every data types you instantiate the template with. For example, if you use a member function of `string` in the `if` block, compilation will fail when instantiating the function with the other data types, since you cannot invoke a method on a primitive type.

Comment: +1 for using overload rather specialization and clearly exposing the various options.

Answer (score 2):

You can move last 3 lines into some function, and use C++ function overloading, i.e. one for bool, second for int etc, i think.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    voud foo (T *) {
        foo ();
    }
    void foo (string *) {
        foo ();
        bar ();
    }
private:
    void foo () {
    }
};
```

Or

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    void foo (T * t) {
        do_foo (t);
    }
    void foo (string * s) {
        do_foo (s);
        bar (s);
    }
private:
    template <typename T>
    void do_foo (T *) {
    }
};
```

You could explicitly specialise Foo::foo *outside* the class.

`tempalte <> void Foo :: foo (string *) {}`

This seems like it could be put to devious use, though...

Comment: Specialization of functions is, in general, a bad idea to get into. I also thought that specialization of member functions within the class/struct itself was forbidden, would you be using VC++ ?

Comment: Luc's GOTW reference about specialisation is good (if heady) reading, but I wouldn't say specialisation of functions is *bad* per se. I've edited my example -- you're right about member specialisation, I fixed my example.

Comment: Well it's not bad per se, but using it is exposing yourself to tricky debug (compile or runtime) sessions. It's a bit like using `new` and `delete` manually. Works fine for now, but complicate future maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to specialise your template for string, as follows:

```
template<> xyz(string* a) { /* code here, including modified lines */ }
```

EDIT: Apparently, I did not notice the "member function" bit of it. The solution would be to add an extra indirection, a function that you specialise for string and call at the end of your current function.

Comment: I don't think you can specialize for member functions.